# MySQL: update table A when elements from table B fulfill some requirements

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm developing an e-commerce website and I need to run an SQL command that update the category of all products that have a category beginning with `'HP '`.
There is a table `PRODUCT` with all products, a table `CATEGORY` with all categories and a table `PRODUCT_CATEGORY` that links `product_id` and `category_id`.

The tables link are:

```
PRODUCT
product_id
icecat_category

PRODUCT_CATEGORY
category_id
product_id

CATEGORY
category_id
category_name
```

The update I would like to perform is:
search all the `PRODUCT.product_id` that have a `CATEGORY.category_name LIKE 'HP %'` and for these items modify the `PRODUCT_CATEGORY.category_id` and set it to the `CATEGORY.category_id` where `CATEGORY.category_name = PRODUCT.icecat_category`.

I am sure it is more difficoult to explain rather to create the right SQL statement, I hope I've been clear enough.

I'm working with:

- MySQL 8.0
- Joomla 4.4.3
- HikaShop 5.0.3

Comment: Could you edit your question to add (in the MarkDown format) a few rows for each table, because I do not understand the logic behind your question?